# Failed to load ressource (Node js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm working on a project with Node js (Express...). I'll try to explain my problem as clear as I can

I work on localhost, and the home page of my index.html allows us to click on buttons which redirect us to other pages.
I found a little game which I would like to put in my project. So I created a button which is supposed to redirect us to the game's html file. (pong.html). And in pong.html, i have a HTML tag  :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pong.js"></script>
```

which is supposed to load the script pong.js and execute it on my page. But I have an error :

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

pong.html is in a "public" folder ; and pong.js is at the root of my project. I don't know if the error comes from a bad redirection in the script tag or in the use of one Nodejs function...
If it can help : the first thing my "pong.js" does after variable declarations is :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
```

Thanks by advance!

Comment: The path in script tag is relative. What I would suggest is create a folder called `js`in your `public` folder and put the `pong.js` file inside it. Now in your `script` tag, the `src`should be `js/pong.js`.

Answer (score 0):

> pong.js is at the root of my project.

It should be near your `pong.html` file

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
```

make public folder static which means localhost:3000/:filenaame can be accessed if file is in that static folder

so for accessing pong.js localhost:3000/pong.js should be address and it should be in static folder

For Eg : 
create pong folder with html and js in public

open localhsot:3000/pong/pong.html it will work then